# Get the content of a spreadsheet in "txt" format using Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using JAVA version of Google Drive API to download spreadsheets. How can i get the content of a spreadsheet in "txt" format or any other format which is searchable?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by manually modifying the exportLink as shown below:

```
if( file.getMimeType().equals("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet")){
    String str= file.getExportLinks().get("application/pdf").replaceFirst("pdf",   
    enter code here"csv&grid=0");
    InputStream input = service
            .getRequestFactory()
            .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(str)).execute().getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is searching, it might be better just use the [search API](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters)
, set the mimeType to be

> application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet

If you want to read the content you might want to export it to OpenOffice SpreadSheet using [exportLinks](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files), then convert the sheet to csv, [there is a link about it](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=6987&highlight=csv%20java).

Comment: I am aware of the Search API but i have to download the content so i can search for a regular expression in it. Can we find any other way rather than converting each an every mime type to text.